# Enable a disabled checkbox in a gridview using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm running into a weird situation. I cannot enable a checkbox in a row.

Currently I have a checkbox in a templatefield in a gridview that I want to become enabled when a document is viewed..

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/documents/{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="document_name"
    Text="View" Target="_blank" > 
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:HyperLinkField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete" SortExpression="complete">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="gv5cbComplete" runat="server"   Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("complete")) %>'
        OnCheckedChanged="GridView5_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="False" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code behind I'm adding a onclick event to the hyperlinkfield via a rowdatabound.

```
string cbid = e.Row.Cells[7].ClientID.ToString();
        ((HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("onclick", "enableGV5CheckBoxFunc(\"" + cbid + "\")");
```

And I've registered a javascript jquery function from the code behind as well.

```
// register script
        StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
        cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + Environment.NewLine);
        cstext.Append("function enableGV5CheckBoxFunc(id){" + Environment.NewLine);
        cstext.Append("window.alert(id);" + Environment.NewLine);
        //cstext.Append("$(\"#\" + id).removeAttr(\"disabled\");" + Environment.NewLine);
        cstext.Append("$(\"#\" + id).prop(\"disabled\", false);" + Environment.NewLine);
        cstext.Append("}</script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname1, cstext.ToString(), false);
```

Now I know that this works in reverse. if the checkbox is enabled and i set .prop(disabled, true) in the jquery it disables the checkbox just fine when i click the hyperlink. However trying to do what I want does not work.

Is there some specific way that I need to do this?

Comment: try `.removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: @Ted that's already commented out. however I did remove that to test and no it didn't make a difference.

Comment: And it is alerting the ID correctly? With no '#' at the beginning?  just checkin. And on a completely side note, just out of curiosity, why not just put the function on the page instead of in the code behind?

Comment: The ID is correct. like I said in the op. If I try the reverse process and attempt to disable the checkbox on click of the hyperlink. The checkbox disables correctly.

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine for me... I did set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the asp:CheckBox for my test...but if it's alerting correctly for you wioth all the asp stuff that gets added to the id then it's not that. Wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to Ted! He got me looking in the right direction.

I switched out

```
string cbid = e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0].ClientID.ToString();
```

to

```
string cbid = e.Row.FindControl("gv5cbComplete").ClientID.ToString();
```

And it works. It would seem that because .NET does a funky addition of

```
<span class="aspNetDisabled">
```

around the checkbox when you disable the checkbox it messes with the id.

Thanks!